# Autenticación en Yahoo Finances API en Android

Tags: android, firebase, oauth2

Me encuentro en un momento en el que necesito autenticar mi cuenta y mi proyecto con las credenciales que Yahoo me ha administrado para poder consumir datos de yahoo.finance. Por una parte tengo el client id y el client secret y aun que he tratado de informarme y documentarme antes de escribir este post me encuentro muy perdido y sin saber que hacer para poder avanzar.

Por una parte tengo esto que esta perfectamnte documentado https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html pro no saco nada en claro..... Y por otro lado me comentaron que firebase puede gestionar la autenticacion. Nose si alguien podria proporcionarme un ejemplo o echarme una mano se lo agradecia me encuentro algo perdido.

Ejemplos que vi por la red la app solicita a el usuario que introduzca sus credenciales de cuenta y correo. Pero yo lo que quiero es mas simple aun. Yo lo que quiero es que una vez la app se ejecute use mis credenciales que yahoo me ha dado a nivel de app en todas las posibles descargas que tenga la app. Ya que yahoo me ofrece realizar tantas peticiones al servior por dia mediante la autenticacion

[image: Esto es lo que yahoo me ha proporcionado]

Comment: ¿Por que para comenzar no haces la autentificacion de correo y contraseña?

Comment: Esq en mi caso es más sencillo por qué no está orientado para que cada usuario se loguee. Sino para que todas los usuarios utilicen mis credenciales.

Comment: Entonces tu no quieres una autentificacion de usuarios, tu quieres autentificar tu programa con el API de Yahoo Finances para obtener sus respectivos valores en tu juego desde internet.

Comment: Correcto diste en el clavo . Yahoo para consumir datos de finanzas hay que autenticar la app. En la página de yql al loguearme puedo hacer querys que me devuelve xml y json pero una vez cojo el html que genera y trató de buscarlo/ejecutarlo me genera un xml vacío donde me dice que debo autenticarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira, si lo que quieres es obtener datos de Yahoo Finances para las respectivas empresas de tu juego de simulación de economia de empresas, solo agrega el API de Yahoo Finances .

Vas a tu Graddle y lo agregas en dependencias :

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.yahoofinance-api', name: 'YahooFinanceAPI', version: 'x.y.z'
}
```

Y ya puedes empezar a usarlo , solo escribes en cualquier parte de tu codigo donde lo vayas a utilizar :

```
Stock stock = YahooFinance.get("INTC");

BigDecimal price = stock.getQuote().getPrice();
BigDecimal change = stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent();
BigDecimal peg = stock.getStats().getPeg();
BigDecimal dividend = stock.getDividend().getAnnualYieldPercent();

stock.print();
```

Lo cual te dara un resultado como este:

INTC

---

symbol: INTC

name: Intel Corporation

currency: USD

stockExchange: NasdaqNM

quote: Ask: 32.25, Bid: 32.24, Price: 32.2485, Prev close: 33.62

stats: EPS: 2.019, PE: 16.65, PEG: 1.74

dividend: Pay date: Mon Dec 01 06:00:00 CET 2014, Ex date: Tue Aug 05 06:00:00 CEST 2014, Annual yield: 2.68%

### history: null

Y listo , solo buscas los simbolos de cada empresa , lo pones y te dara sus valores.

He sacado todo del [sitio del API](http://financequotes-api.com/)

Comment: Llevo bastante mirando este tema y no encontré esa página.... nose me parece muy fácil ojalá sea así jajaj lo probaré luego y te comento gracias tío

Comment: @EduardoMéndez Es facil, suerte! . Si te funciona , mato dos preguntas de un tiro.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpyopc61alnzy31/Captura.JPG?dl=0 me pasa esto segun añadi el gradel hice un rebuild y peta :( sabes a que puede deberse? @EduardoRicardez

Comment: @EduardoMéndez Jajajaja si , porque no creo que exista una version que sea x.y.z jajajaja es una referencia, debes poner la version del API , si miras arriba hay un boton en el sitio que dice descargar y dice la version del API , el cual es v3.6.1 , asi que debes agregar esa version al final.
 compile group: 'com.yahoofinance-api', name: 'YahooFinanceAPI', version: '3.6.1'

Comment: funciono a la perfeccion !!

Comment: @EduardoMéndez Me alegro ;D